# Render Blurriness in Blender 2.79

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I've had an issue with this render where every time I render the scene, there is always blurriness in the areas of shadow/transparency.

[image: Circled are the areas where I am noticing blurriness/blotchiness]

To combat this, I've previously attempted to increase the render resolution, the sample size, and I have confirmed I am using the Cycles Render Engine with GPU Computing.

[image: Here are all of the render settings used for the previous image]

I have also applied denoising with default denoising settings to this render, but I am still running into this issue. Does anyone have recommendations to fix this?

Comment: Hello :). This looks a lot like denoising artifacts. Since Blender 2.81 there is *Intel Denoiser*, which gives way better results.